# Indexing MongoDB Using mongolite R Does Not Give Speed Boost

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

From reading the mongolite manual https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/query-data.html it states I should see a speed boost if I index the columns I will most often be filtering by.

I have a data frame of stocks Open, Hi, Lo, Close prices. The df is about 60k rows. Here is a glimpse.

```
head(df.ts$find())
 price_open price_high price_low price_close   ref_date ticker   SMA200
1     279.64     279.80    278.84      279.34 2018-07-16    SPY 267.8959
2     278.47     280.91    278.41      280.47 2018-07-17    SPY 268.0465
3     280.56     281.18    280.06      281.06 2018-07-18    SPY 268.1956
4     280.31     280.74    279.46      280.00 2018-07-19    SPY 268.3340
5     279.77     280.48    279.50      279.68 2018-07-20    SPY 268.4681
6     279.45     280.43    279.06      280.20 2018-07-23    SPY 268.6033
```

I am only doing a query where I filter by stock and collect the the rest of the data set.

```
system.time({
df = df.ts$find(
  query = '{"ticker" : "SPY" }',
  fields = '{"_id" : false, "price_close" : true, "ref_date" : true, "SMA200" : true}'
)
})

Imported 267 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
   user  system elapsed 
   0.00    0.00    0.13
```

As you can see this takes me about .15 seconds to retrieve.
Listening to the manual I set the ticker as an index column.

```
df.ts$index(add = '{"ticker" : 1}')
```

I now re run the code in anticipation of a speed boost.

```
 system.time({
    df = df.ts$find(
      query = '{"ticker" : "SPY" }',
      fields = '{"_id" : false, "price_close" : true, "ref_date" : true, "SMA200" : true}'
    )
    })

    Imported 267 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
       user  system elapsed 
       0.00    0.00    0.14
```

You can see there was no speed boost. Is there a solution to this problem? In the manual the author was able to see a HUGE speed boost.

Comment: Indexes will make a difference if you have a relatively selective search against a larger collection of documents or your data set is larger than available RAM (since the index can be searched rather than scanning all documents). If you only have about 60,000 documents per the schema in your `find()` output I'm guesstimating that's about 10MB of data, which should easily fit in RAM. A huge speed boost is unlikely for the current size of your data set, but the difference will be more appreciable as your data and query volumes scale.

Comment: @Stennie But still, in this case, we are avoiding collection scan by creating an index on `ticker` column. So we should see some improvement in the timing ryt?

Comment: If your total data set is currently  ~10MB a collection scan is unlikely to be resource intensive. You could try to [explain your query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) in the `mongo` shell for comparison. Where is your database deployment relative to your R application? Are they both on the same machine? There are several aspects of performance you could consider measuring: time to execute the query, time to transfer the result set, and time to serialise the result set into a dataframe. An index will help if the query is slow to execute.